# Writing a proper data model in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I'm trying to write a Django model, but as I read further and further in the docs, I find out that I have to take care about too many things and I'm getting really confused with all the considerations I have to bear in mind.

My most essential doubt is "When I define two classes, in which do I include the reference to the other when..."

- a) class A has only one class B instances
- b) class A must have one
  and just one class B instance
- c) class A has many class B instances
- d) class A is a type of class B (so as Restaurant is a type of
  Business)

"... and how do I create/manage these two classes when creating those objects".

I hope someone may explain it easier. I think that with these four things clear I may be able to write the model myself.

Comment: I haven't got any experience in Django, but do recommend you to read carefully at the docs about the data modelling, and you will probably get to learn how it really works.

Comment: ... what's the question? How does that code fail your specification? Where did you get stuck? Please clarify.

Comment: @Bakuriu the question is simply "how can I write a model that fits all of those requirements", I get stuck in that it is so complex, that I don't really know where to start from. The code I've written doesn't do all of the things I need. If you read both things you'll see that it misses.

Comment: @Bakuriu I've re-written my question hugely to clarify it. Hope now it helps more.

Comment: for a) use `OneToOneField` with both `blank` and `null` set to True, for b) use `OneToOneField`,  for c) use `ForeignKey`, for d) use `model inheritance`.  but i think you can't fulfil all the four requirement at the same time.

Comment: @Enix it's not at the same time, there are different cases, I just called them the same to simplify. Thank you. If you post it as an answer with a bit of explanation i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Django document is still a good place for you to start, and it is really comprehensive for both beginners and professionals. No other shortcut to master it except reading its document and playing with the example.*

## case a) class A has only one class B instances

**`UserModel` stands for `A`, `UserProfile` stands for `B`.**

Suppose we have a `UserModel`, and need one more table to keep the extra information, let's say `UserProfile`. And we allow `UserProfile` to be null. then we can use `OneToOneField` to bind these two class.

### model definition

```
from django.db import models

class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('username', max_length=20)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField('nick name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    # blank tells the validator, this field could be blank, and null tells the db engine, this field could be null.
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel, blank=True, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### How to access A from B and vice versa

```
u = UserModel.objects.get(pk=1)
nickname = u.userprofile.nickname    # to access B from A, you can use the model name lowercase name for reference.

profile = UserModel.objects.get(pk=1)
username = profile.user.username     # To access A from B, you can use the model name lowercase name for reference.
```

## case b) class A must have one and just one class B instance

**`UserModel` stands for `A`, `UserProfile` stands for `B`.**

For the model definition, it is almost the same as case a). But we need to make sure B is coexistence with A, so we will need to remove `Blank` and `null`. And we must use `post_save` hook to make suer B is also created with A is saved.

### Model definition

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save

class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('username', max_length=20)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField('nick name', max_length=50)
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserModel)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    # This hook is automatically called when the UserModel is created, this is used to make suer UserProfile is also created when UserModel is created.
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

### How to access A from B and vice versa

*The same as case a).*

## case c) class A has many class B instances

**`Author` stands for `A`, `Book` stands for `B`.**

For example, `Author` is a model to save the book author information, and one author may write zero or many books, let's named it to `Book` as model. (Suppose only allow one author for each book).

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name of the author', max_length=20)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField('name of the book', max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')
```

### How to access A from B and vice versa

```
# access B from A
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
books = author.books
# first book
book_name = books[0].book_name

# access A from B
book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
author_name = book.author.name
```

If you allow one book has many authors, then we should use `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeignKey`. The `Book` model definition changed to this:

```
class BookAuthor(models.Model):
    author = model.ForeignKey(Author)
    book = model.ForeignKey(Book)
    publish_at = model.DateTimeField(auto_add=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField('name of the book', max_length=50)
    # through is used to tell django, we have defined another relationship table to bind Author and Book model.
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='BookAuthor')
```

### How to access A from B and vice versa

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
first_book_name = author.book_set.order_by('publish_at')[0].book_name

book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
author_names = [author.name for author in book.author_set.all()]
```

## case d) class A is a type of class B (so as Restaurant is a type of Business)

**`Place` stands for `B`, `Library` and `Restaurant` stands for `A`.**

For example, we defined a generic class `Place`, and `Library` could be a place, same as `Restaurant`.

### Model definition

```
class Place(models.Model):
   address = models.CharField('address', max_length=100)

class Library(Place):
   num_of_books = models.IntegerField('NO. of books in the library')

class Restaurant(Place):
   restaurant_type = models.CharField('The type of the restaurant', max_length=10)
```

### How to use A and B

```
lib = Library.objects.get(pk=1)
lib.address  # get the library address
lib.num_of_books  # get the no. of books in this library 

rest = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
rest.address  # get the restaurant address
rest.restaurant_type  # get the restaurant type
```

For the above case, django will create a `Place` table in db, because it is also a model, if you don't what it to be created, and treat it as `Abstract` class as other programming language, you can redefined it as follow:

```
class Place(models.Model):
   address = models.CharField('address', max_length=100)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

Comment: Thank you soy much. That was loads of help.